# How to make EF generate better Many to Many key names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

I have the following DB schema:
[image]

In a nutshell, it's a cross-reference. Part "A" can cross reference to many target parts.

EF generates the PartCrossReference like this

```
public partial class PartCrossReference
{
    public int SourcePartId { get; set; }
    public int TargetPartId { get; set; }
    public string CrossType { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public virtual Part Part { get ; set; }
    public virtual Part Part1 { get ; set; }
}
```

I think "Part" and "Part1" are not appropriate names for the Cross Referenced `Part` objects. They should be "SourcePart" and "TargetPart", like the keys. How do I do this, and if it's a T4 template, hopefully you can be specific, because that seems like much deeper water.

Comment: Is this a code 1st model or are you generating EF from the DB?

Comment: The MSDN documentation calls this "Code Second". Basically, it's a reverse engineer using the Power Tools. It's Code First generated from an existing DB.

Comment: Ok... And you simply want the generator to automagically use SourcePart instead of Part and TargetPart instead of Part1.

I'm guessing you can manually change the virtual object names from Part and Part1 to what you're desiring.  But it sounds like you're seeking this to be automagic?

Comment: I would like it generated that way, since we are in the middle of development and I don't want to have to edit that file every time I regenerate the models.

Comment: In the ideal world, I'm sold on the idea...

But why not generate the model once, and then enable migrations on the DB and simply use code first methodologies going forward?

The only challenge for you on this that comes to the top of my head is the matrixed org and requiring DBA gods to potentially help and/or authorize modifying a PROD db.

Comment: Mainly because we are on a very tight schedule, and I already know how to deploy my db using SSDT, and the SSDT deploy is already working.

Comment: k...  I've not done anything in the realm of customizing T4 nor generating models from the DB.  Most of the stuff I've done recently is code 1st...

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past:

```
public partial class PartCrossReference
{
    public int SourcePartId { get; set; }
    public int TargetPartId { get; set; }
    public string CrossType { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public virtual Part Part { get ; set; }
    public virtual Part Part1 { get ; set; }
}

ClassExtend:("^/partial/*").Generate();
```

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. Could you expand on that a little? I'm guessing that goes somewhere in the T4 template. Any idea where? I'm a newbie with t4.